# Finding a cell with Sum Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am using '.HasFormula' to identify cells in a range. i want to find cells that have a 'sum' formula, and keep those, but keep all the other formulas.

```
'If it has Formula
If wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13").HasFormula Then

'If it is a Sum Formula                               
If wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13").HasFormula.Find("=SUM()", xlFormulas) Then
    wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13:" & GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents    
Else 
'Nothing

End If
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Just commented below

Comment: What have you done till now? Do you want to check if cell contains SUM in entire formula or it starts from SUM?

Comment: if the cell starts with =SUM()

Comment: Please put the code in the original post using [edit] and not in the comments.

Comment: Assuming your `GetColumnLetter` function is just allowing you to use `Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13")` instead of using `Cells(13, iColumn)`, it appears that you are wanting to find `=SUM` in row 13 only and, if found, clear all the contents of that column from row 13 downwards.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, 
Could you loop through all your cells in the '.HasFormula' Range
Then compare the '.formula' to see if it is a sum, 
creating a collection of just those cells.

Sorry I would put cod but I am not entirely sure what you are try to do yet, could you post your code snippet and I will update my answer better for you. Good luck :)

Comment: If wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13").HasFormula Then
                               
                               If wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13").HasFormula.Find("=SUM()", xlFormulas) Then
                                wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & "13:" & GetColumnLetter(iColumn) & wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents